# Converting C# to VB: New... With {Read-Only Property}

Tags: c#, vb.net, initialization, dotnet-httpclient, code-conversion

In trying to convert the following C# code from a tutorial (by hand, since cross-compilers I have tried don't seem to be able to do this):

```
httpClient = new HttpClient(unrelated args)
{
    DefaultRequestHeaders = 
    { 
        Accept = { MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json") } 
    }
}
```

The closest I have been able to get it is:

```
Dim httpClient As New HttpClient(unrelated args) With
{
    .DefaultRequestHeaders [=[New HttpRequestHeaders]] [With] 
    {
        .Accept = {MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json") 
    }
}
```

(where I have tried various combinations of the values in brackets)

No matter what I try, the best I can get is the error

> Property `DefaultRequestHeaders` is `ReadOnly`.

I have confirmed that `.DefaultRequestHeaders` and `.Accept` are ReadOnly in both VB and C#. Apparently C# is able to write to ReadOnly properties at initialization? Is VB not able to do this as well, or is there some nuance of syntax I am missing to be able to do this? Failing being able to set this at initialization, some other way to set the actual value would presumably work; unfortunately, I don't see a constructor that exposes it, so I don't see any other way to accomplish this, though I would also welcome any suggestion along those lines.

Comment: In C#, this syntax doesn't set the property; it just sets properties on its value.

Comment: I should have also mentioned that I tried setting the Accept property itself directly, both in this construct and separately after initialization. The Accept property is also ReadOnly.

Comment: Yes; that's the same feature.  This compiles to `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have confirmed that .DefaultRequestHeaders and .Accept are ReadOnly in both VB and C#. Apparently C# is able to write to ReadOnly properties at initialization?

Nope. C# cannot write to read-only properties any more than VB can. But read-only properties can return an object that can be written to.

What you are looking at are C# *collection initializers*. They allow you to create collections in one line without having to call `Add` again and again.

VB also has [collection initialzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/), but the syntax is very different. That said, it is not 100% necessary to do it that way, especially if you are only adding a single item to the collection.

```
Dim httpClient As New HttpClient(args As unrelated) 'Assuming unrelated is a type (not sure)
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the collection initializers link! Knowing what to call something is half the battle, half the time. I still can't find a syntax that lets me use the collection initializer inside the initializer for the HttpClient, as it still complains that the `.DefaultRequestHeaders` is ReadOnly, but the `Add` method seems to be doing the job.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently nested object and collection initializers for properties is not supported in VB. There was a discussion in 2011 to support it, but I guess it went no where. The current discussion seems to be from July, 2017:

https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/134

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that `Accept` is a collection. Instead of trying to set the entire collection, I called `Add` once the variable was created, and it appears to be working now.